# I want to have this angular code to return multiple result instead of one

Tags: angular

I am currently modifying an Angular code for ionic example and is still learning how to have multiple results returned. However, from this code, I understand that it can only display one result instead of multiple result.

I have tried looking around for solutions but none seems to describe specifically how to solve my dilemma. Because I am trying to speed up my learning process, modifying an existing project is the fastest way I can learn. This is the link to which I have downloaded and modified the ionic example: https://github.com/typeorm/ionic-example

In home.ts, I have changed the code to the following:

```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
   import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
   import { getRepository, Repository } from 'typeorm';

   import { Author } from '../../entities/author';
   import { Category } from '../../entities/category';
   import { Post } from '../../entities/post';

  @Component({
     selector: 'page-home',
     templateUrl: 'home.html'
  })

  export class HomePage {
     private savedPost: boolean = false;
     private loadedPost: Post = null;

     constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) { }

     ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.runDemo();
     }

    async runDemo() {
       const authors_array:Author[]=[];
       const categories_array:Category[]=[];
       const posts_array:Post[]=[];
       const author = new Author();
       const secondAuthor = new Author();
       author.name = "Person";
       authors_array.push(author);
       secondAuthor.name = "Niema";
       authors_array.push(secondAuthor);

       const category = new Category();
       category.name = "TypeScript";
       categories_array.push(category);
       const secondCategory = new Category();
       secondCategory.name = "Fantasy";
       categories_array.push(secondCategory);
       const thirdCategory = new Category();
       thirdCategory.name = "Programming";
       categories_array.push(thirdCategory);

       const post = new Post();
       post.title = "Control flow based type analysis";
       post.text = `TypeScript 2.0 implements a control flow-based type analysis for local variables and parameters.`;
       post.categories = [categories_array[0], categories_array[2]];
       post.author = authors_array[0];
       posts_array.push(post);

       const secondPost = new Post();
       secondPost.title = "Some insane sci-fi";
       secondPost.text = `Planet busting adventure`;
       secondPost.categories = [categories_array[1]];
       secondPost.author = authors_array[1];
       posts_array.push(secondPost);

       console.log('authors_array', authors_array);
       console.log('categories_array', categories_array);
       console.log('posts_array', posts_array);


       const postRepository = getRepository('post') as Repository<Post>;
       await postRepository.save(posts_array[0]);
       await postRepository.save(posts_array[1]);

       console.log("Post has been saved");
       this.savedPost = true;

       /**Up until here, the result is expected. How can I modify the 
       postRepository to get and display multiple result?**/ 

       const loadedPost = await postRepository.createQueryBuilder('post')
       .innerJoinAndSelect('post.author', 'author')
       .innerJoinAndSelect('post.categories', 'categories')
       .where('post.id = :id', {id: post.id})
       .getOne();

        console.log("Post has been loaded: ", loadedPost);
       this.loadedPost = loadedPost;
  }

  getCategories() {
    if(this.loadedPost) {
      return this.loadedPost.categories.map(cat => cat.name).join(", ");
    }
    return '';
  }

}
```

1. How do I change the query to return me all the value in the database?
2. I suspect that I will need a new entities object to cater to the new display form. Is my suspicion justified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getMany` instead of `getOne`

```
const loadedPost = await postRepository.createQueryBuilder('post')
  .innerJoinAndSelect('post.author', 'author')
  .innerJoinAndSelect('post.categories', 'categories')
  .getMany();
```

Change `loadedPost` type to array as well:

```
private loadedPost: Post[] = [];
```

You can learn more about TypeORM query builder in here: https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/getting-values-using-querybuilder

Comment: This work. Thank you. :) I'll take note of the url reference you've given